# Report Builder 3.0 - Disable Parameter Dropdown if no Results

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

For the sake of example, the user selects a Car Manufacturer from the param dropdown, and then the Car Model param dropdown becomes available with only cars from that manufacturer. E.g. if a user selects `Honda`, from the Car Manufacturer dropdown, they will be able to select `Civic`, `Accord`, etc from the Car Model dropdown.

In my use case, some manufacturers have no Car Models. By default, the dropdown is blank.

Is there any way to disable it and/or display a message when no Car Models match the selected Manufacturer multi-select.

There is an answer of "Not possible" here, but it's over half a decade old:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c8130b45-34c0-4255-9f72-2e3837c8c37c/enable-and-disable-parameters-by-selecting-one-of-the-value-from-drop-down-list-in-ssrs-report?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify exactly how you want the situation to be handled, but I'll give you some pointers. You can't completely disable the Model parameter, so you need to provide a placeholder value.

For example, you could update the query in the dataset that provides the Model values. When it returns no results `UNION` an "N/A" value to the list. You can also set it to select the first model by default so they don't have to actually pick this.

Then you would need to update the main query to ignore this fake model name. So you are essentially making the parameter optional even though it's still there.

Comment: Steven, I appreciate the answer - I did come up with that solution as well, but that seems to be almost as confusing from a user's point of view. Still, it's probably the best we can do.